# Trouble with a pointer not being initialized

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to make a program that asks for a users name and the amount of money they owe to the company. The problem is, every time I try to compile the program I get this warning saying that "user may not be initialized." I'm not quite sure what that means. Any help to out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
#define END  '\0'        
#define LENGTH 20          

struct info
{
   char  lastName[LENGTH]; 
   float payment;
};

int customerS();
void accounts(struct info *userStart, int amount);
void changeNames(struct info *userStart, int amount);
void sort(struct info *userStart, int amount);
void results(struct info *userStart, int amount);

int main()
{
   struct info *user;
   int amount;

    while((amount = customers()) != 0)
   {

      accounts(user, amount);
      changeNames(user, amount);
      sortNames(user, amount);
      results(user, amount);
      free(user);
   }

   return 0;
}

int customers()
{
   int choice;

   do
   {      
      printf("\nHow many customers do you have (2 to 300, 0=quit): ",
      scanf("%d", &choice);
   }
   while((choice < 2|| choice > 300) && choice != 0);
return choice;
}

void accounts(struct info *userStart, int amount)
{
   struct info *user;
   char   *name[LENGTH];
   float  owed;

   for(user = userStart; (user - userStart) < amount; user++)
   {
      scanf (" %s", name[LENGTH]);
      getchar();
      do
      {
         name[LENGTH] = getchar();
         name[LENGTH]++;
      }
      while(!('\n'));
      user->lastName[LENGTH + 1] = END;
      scanf("%f", &owed);
      user->payment = owed;
   }
   return;
}

void changeNames(struct info *userStart, int amount)
{
   char *fast = &userStart->lastName[LENGTH],
        *slow = &userStart->lastName[LENGTH];

   if(tolower(*fast))
      *slow++ = toupper(*fast);       
   while(*fast != END)
   {
      if(!isspace(*fast) || isalpha(*fast))
         *slow++ = tolower(*fast);
      fast++;
   }
   *slow = END;
   return;
}

void sort(struct info *userStart, int amount)
{
   struct info *user;
   char *in,
        *out,
        temp;

   for(out = user->lastName; (out - userStart->lastName) < amount; out++)
   {
      for(in = out + 1; (in - userStart->lastName) < amount; in++)
      {
         if(strcmp(user->lastName, userStart->lastName))
         {
            temp = *out;
            *out = *in;
            *in = temp;
         }
      }
   }
   return;
}
void results(struct info *userStart, int amount)
{
   struct info *user;
   printf("\nName: %s        Payment: $%.2f", user->lastName,  user->payment);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about asking a question like this. I would have asked my teacher, but he is gone for the night. Thanks to anyone that helps me out though.

Comment: Fyi, the protoype for `customer()` should be `customers()`, and no definition of the symbol `QUIT`. The former is a problem; the latter a show-stopper. We can't compile it, much less test it. Unrelated, dumping the result of `scanf` into the argument list for `printf` ? was that intentional?

Comment: The error is you actually asked about is explicit: you declare a pointer, `user` in `main`. You pass this *indeterminate* pointer (it was given no formal address, nor NULL) to `accounts`, where it is promptly used for various things. The compiler is telling you that's probably wrong, and it's *definitely* right. Frankly, there are a ton of things wrong in this code, but that was the one you asked about, and hopefully you understand the problem now.

Comment: Okay so I was able to compile it, but now when I try to enter a name, I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well I see that user is not initialized. Where in the code do you suppose user gets initialized?

Comment: when writing a function prototype, like: `int customerS();`  1) the function name must match the actual function name.  2) a prototype for a function that takes no parameters needs to be written as: `int customerS( void );`  so the compiler does not produce code that will enable that function to take any number of parameters.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code does not compile, amongst other things, it is missing the needed include statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understaning, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `char *fast = &userStart->lastName[LENGTH],`  this is setting `fast` to point to 1 character past the end of the field `lastName`

Comment: in C, the index into an array starts with 0 and ends with (number of entries in array -1)

Comment: @user3629249 also, the `S` should be `s`

Comment: regarding: `while((amount = customers()) != 0)`  this statement, in `main()`, results in the user of the program being ask, for every customer, how many customers will be entered.  Suggest moving the call to `customers()` to before the `main()` loop and using the resulting variable: `amount` in the `main()` loop

Comment: regarding: `for(user = userStart; (user - userStart) < amount; user++)`  this is performing pointer arithmetic.  so comparing that difference in pointers with `amount` will not perform the desired operation.  Perhaps you might use: `for(user = userStart; (user - userStart) < (amount*sizeof( *user ) ); user++)`

Comment: @user3629249 the sizeof calculation is not correct. Pointer arithmetic will do the right thing during that difference calculation, so long as `user` and `userStart` are both in the same sequence or the one-past address. The OP's code in that for-loop is actually correct. There are *plenty* of places where things are wrong, but that isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

struct info *user;

This allocates a pointer to a user struct, not the struct itself.

So, you can allocate it on the stack via `struct info user;` and pass &user to the functions, or dynamically allocated it via `user = (struct info*)malloc( sizeof(struct info) )`.

Either way should avoid your segmentation fault (because the pointer is not initialized).
..)

Comment: Okay, I allocated it, but I'm still getting a segmentation fault. I think the problem may be in the accounts function. I'll try changing some things up there.

Comment: A less complicated, easy to code, review and maintain allocation is `user = malloc(sizeof *user);`.